# How to add more button at the end of UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have been working on this for a long time.
I need to expand and collapse the `UILabel` text on click of a button located at the end of text of `UILabel`.

Thinks I have tried
I have use VSWordDetector to detect which word of `UILabel` get tapped but it not gave correct word tapped.

Comment: Why don't you simply change the frame of the label? Give it a smaller or bigger frame depending on the context.

Comment: Split label into two, and calculate the frame and visibility of second one. Second one can be used to detect the tap.

Comment: A simple button underneath the label...

Comment: Well thank you for your feedback guys... Valentin'a answer is what i am looking for..

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you just use `UIButton` without visible frame with `titleLabel.text` `@"..."` or `@"▼"`.
So, for example, you have a string `@"Some long long, really long string which couldn't be presented in one line"`. Then take a substring for `UILabel` text, and put a button described above on the right from your label. Add an action for ▼-buuton to update `label.text` and hide button.
Code snippet:

```
@interface YourClass

@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel* longStringLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton* moreButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* text;

@end

@implementation YourClass

// Some method, where you add subviews, for example viewDidLoad
{
// ...
    self.longStringLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44);
    [self addSubview:self.longStringLabel];

    self.moreButton.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.longStringLabel.frame), 0, 20, 44);
    [self addSubview:self.moreButton];
// ...
}

- (UILabel*)longStringLabel
{
    if (!_longStringLabel)
    {
        _longStringLabel = [UILabel new];
        _longStringLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
    }

    return _longStringLabel;
}

- (UIButton*)moreButton
{
    if (!_moreButton)
    {
        _moreButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        _moreButton.titleLabel.text = @"▼";
        [_moreButton addTarget:self action:@selector(moreButtonDidTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    return _moreButton;
}

- (void)moreButtonDidTap:(UIButton*)sender
{
    self.longStringLabel.frame = [self.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.longStringLabel.frame.size.width + self.moreButton.frame.size.width, 100)
                                                         options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                      attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : self.longStringLabel.font }
                                                         context:nil];
    self.longStringLabel.text = self.text;

    self.moreButton.hidden = YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: Well This is what i was looking for...i am new to Objective-C so can you please post some code regarding the same...